# Validate a form using Angular-material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How Can I validate a form using Angular-material, I need two functionalities:
1) When click submit show error messages if required fields are empty.
2) Do not send post request(avoid submit) if form fields are not valid.
The next code avoid submit but it does not show error messages when clicking, only when cursor is going out of each input field.

```
 <form name="userForm">
<md-input-container>
    <input name="email" placeholder="Email" data-ng-model="vm.registerUserData.email" required />
    <div ng-messages="userForm.email.$error" ng-if='userForm.myControl.$dirty'>
      <div ng-message="required">This is required!</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container>
    <input name="Password" placeholder="Password" data-ng-model="vm.registerUserData.password" required />
     <div ng-messages="userForm.Password.$error">
     <div ng-message="required">This is required!</div>
     </div>
 </md-input-container>                             

 <md-input-container>
    <md-button id="registerUser" value="Register" class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="userForm.$valid &&  vm.registerUser()" aria-label="login" ng-disabled="login.loginForm.$invalid()">
      Create
     </md-button>
</md-input-container>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're missing 2 things.

**First:** add `type="submit"` to your `md-button` element.

**Second:** add `novalidate` to your `form` element:

> Note that [novalidate](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) is used to disable browser's native form validation.

You should also consider using `ng-submit` on the `form` element instead of using `ng-click` on the button.

```
<form name="userForm" novalidate ng-submit="userForm.$valid &&  vm.registerUser()">
    <md-input-container>
        <input name="email" placeholder="Email" data-ng-model="vm.registerUserData.email" required />
        <div ng-messages="userForm.email.$error" ng-if='userForm.myControl.$dirty'>
            <div ng-message="required">This is required!</div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container>
        <input name="Password" placeholder="Password" data-ng-model="vm.registerUserData.password" required />
        <div ng-messages="userForm.Password.$error">
            <div ng-message="required">This is required!</div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>                             

    <md-input-container>
        <md-button type="submit" id="registerUser" value="Register" class="md-raised md-primary" aria-label="login" ng-disabled="login.loginForm.$invalid()">
            Create
        </md-button>
    </md-input-container>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Jhon, it works perfect. Just one more thing, do you know how is it  possible to hide/clean the error message as soon as i start typing into the input field?

Comment: Try to add `ngMessages` directly to your module as well.